# Cannot save multiple files to database with Foreign Key

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures, file-upload

In my MVC application I have two tables called **Ticket** and **Attachment** and I want to save attachments for per ticket. The problem is that: I need to save multiple attachments with the **TicketID** **when creating a new ticket**. So, I think I should create a new ticket in the Ticket table and then get its ID and save all the attachments with this TicketID to the Attachment table in a loop. I have look at many web sites and stackoverflow, but there is not such a kind of problem or solution on that pages. Any idea?

**Note:** I use Entity Framework Code First, but I can also use Stored Procedure or SQL command for this operation.

Here are these two models:

```
public class Ticket
{
    [Key] 
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    //... removed for clarifty
}
```

```
public class Attachment
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    //Foreign key for Ticket
    public int TicketID { get; set; }

    public byte[] FileData { get; set; }

    public string FileMimeType { get; set; }    
}
```

And the controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = null)] TicketViewModel viewModel 
/* contains both model: Ticket and Attachment */, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //??? First I need to save Ticket
        repository.SaveTicket(viewModel.Ticket);  

        foreach(var f in files)
        {
            viewModel.Attachment.FileMimeType = f.ContentType;
            viewModel.Attachment.FileData = new byte[f.ContentLength];
            f.InputStream.Read(viewModel.Attachment.FileData , 0, f.ContentLength);

            //??? Then save all attachment. But no idea how to get TicketID      
            repository.SaveAttachment(viewModel.Attachment); 
        }
    }   
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID property will be automatically filled by EF after a SaveChanges. Your code can then use it. I assume that the viewModel.Ticket object is the actual object saved to the database. If not, please also post the `SaveTicket` method.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = null)] TicketViewModel viewModel 
/* contains both model: Ticket and Attachment */, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // assumes viewModel.Ticket is the actual entity saved, and SaveChanges is called.  
        repository.SaveTicket(viewModel.Ticket);  

        foreach(var f in files)
        {
            viewModel.Attachment.FileMimeType = f.ContentType;
            viewModel.Attachment.FileData = new byte[f.ContentLength];
            f.InputStream.Read(viewModel.Attachment.FileData , 0, f.ContentLength);

            // fill ticket id
            viewModel.Attachment.TicketID = viewModel.Ticket.ID;
            repository.SaveAttachment(viewModel.Attachment); 
        }
    }   
    return View();
}
```

If you want to do everything in one transaction, you can add the childs immediatly, and SaveChanges will save all objects:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = null)] TicketViewModel viewModel 
/* contains both model: Ticket and Attachment */, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var ticket = viewModel.Ticket;

        foreach(var f in files)
        {
            var attachment = new Attachment();
            attachment.FileMimeType = f.ContentType;
            attachment.FileData = new byte[f.ContentLength];
            f.InputStream.Read(attachment.FileData , 0, f.ContentLength);

            ticket.Attachments.Add(attachment);
        }

        // this will save the ticket and attachments
        repository.SaveTicket(ticket);
    }   
    return View();
}
```

Your Ticket class will have to look like this:

```
public class Ticket
{
    [Key] 
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    // EF will now to use the foreign key to the attachment table
    public virtual ICollection<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The actual object is Ticket and I need to insert Ticket model first and then Attachment model bu using the ID value of newly added Ticket in order to use this ID as TicketID of the Ticket records in one transaction. So, maybe I need to make this definitions on database layer, but I am not sure to pass IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> or Attachment[] array to the database side. Could you update your answer by giving these option as 2nd choice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is fine how you are creating the objects here. What exactly are you looking for? Do you want to do everything in one transaction?

Comment: Yes, I want to create Ticket and each Attachment belonging to this Ticket (FK is TicketID) in one transaction. So, I have the following troubles: **1)**  I have to pass Attachment as IEnumerable, because I have several attachments at one insert. How can I pass it to the database layer? **2)** I am not sure if I can rollback the SaveChanges method. I meant that first I am calling **context.Issues.Add(Ticket);** and then call **context.FileAttachments.Add(fa);** in a loop (I also set FileAttachment.TicketID=Ticket.ID in this loop), and finally call **context.SaveChanges();**. Is that true?

Comment: I updated the answer with a second solution 15 minutes ago :), that should work for you

Comment: Many thanks for your help Rob. Although there are some kind of errors, I fixed all of them and now it is working. As you said, there is no need to assign **FileAttachment.TicketID=Ticket.ID** and the only key point is to define navigation properties that I had already done. Now I return both **viewmodel.Ticket** and **viewmodel.Attachments** collection to the data layer and call Add method for both of them. Finally calling SaveChanges method finishes the transaction.